# difference between (int)object and int.parse(object.ToString())

Tags: c#, casting

when I write

```
(int)dataTable1.Rows[0]["field1"]
```

I get an error that this is an invalid cast.
The value in "field1" is "20"

when I do this

```
int.parse(dataTable1.Rows[0]["field1"].ToString())
```

it works.

But why can `(int)dataTable1.Rows[0]["field1"]` not be casted to an int when the value is "20".
What is the difference with int.parse ?

Comment: So if I understand it right in @Sklivvz answer of the duplicate, casting like (int)object means threat the object as if it where an int. And because "20" is a string not an int, it will fail. Is this correct ?

Comment: Basically, yes.  There's no direct cast from a string to an integer.  But a string can potentially be *parsed* to an integer.  I haven't actually seen the source code for `int.Parse()`, but I'd wager it's doing something other than casting.